# Display of informative message over SQA site

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Yesterday, I saw a message flashing over SO site which was somewhat like informing people for accepting and voting questions and answers ("Welcome back, if you like or find the answer helpful make sure to upvote or accept the answer").

Can we show same kind of message over SQA site too, I think doing this may encourage more members to accept and upvote the questions/answers and this in turn may increase the Accepted answers percentage too. Again, I saw that over other Stack Exchange sites (SO, Travel etc.) lots of people upvote answers as compared to SQA (I admit community/participant size also play role in this matter), so this gap might also get covered by such informative/encouraging messages.

Update:-

So, here I have something to show now. After few xyz actions I am now able to get that message again over the SO site and it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe this kind of thing is related to your rep. If you have under 200 rep, you might see that on some of the other sites, where you won't when you're on established sites. I am prepared to be corrected though.

Comment: I have updated the question for the image of the message shown over SO. Please have a look over it :)

Comment: I have literally no idea what that banner is. =( It could be only Stack Overflow? Do you get it on any beta sites that you're <200 rep on?

Comment: No, I haven't joined anyother beta where I have less than 200 score, I have this score count on SO only. May be this message is only for SO site. But is there a way to request for such a message (including QPD) over SQA too (just a query).

Comment: I'll talk to the team about it and get back to you. Hopefully sooner than [six to eight weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/147335).

Comment: Thanks for the update and information :)

Answer (score 3):

I noticed this the flashing messages on SO when downvoting question to please let a comment or flag to "show what's going wrong" (not cited but I think you get it). I couldn't see that this is depent from the reputation. Okay as I can enter the first review queues on SO I also have enough reputation to comment but I can't imagine that this is relatied to the users reputation.

I never noticed a flashing message like you mentioned about remembering people to accept / upvote answers. I would like to see more accept / upvoted answers on SO and SQA as well (the only two sites I'm in).

Espically more accepted answers would help the SQA site. According the [SQA-Beta Overview at Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2241/software-quality-assurance-testing) we could improve at this topic. Main problem stays the content but this is on another page - especially in such a specific topic like SQA.

I think the main "problem" of many SQA-questions is that they are broad and based on experience like "What shall I do to improve my QA carrer". We have less "fact based content" like SO. Sure we have many selenium questions about how to "programm" this or that but we also have many indiviually questions where people ask for adviese. If they can create real solutions with these, like convincing management to use tool XYZ, is very complicated to identify.

For myself I have this question about automation tools for [GUPTA applications](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11516/tool-for-automatic-gui-testing-of-gupta-windows-applications). I didn't upvoted or accepted any of the answers because all tools didn't help me to solve the problem - because the problem seems to be part of GUPTA/Windows itselfs and not by the choice of the tool. In the past I already thought several times of deleting the question because of that but then decided to let it open as it got five upvotes what shows me other users are interested in that topic too. But will I ever get a working solution so I can accept this answer? I doubt about that.

If we here on SQA would move defintion questions to a "wiki" (like the announced documentation feature on SO) and also putting those "what tool can I have"-like questions together our content would be much more less.

So yes: Any option to improve the acceptance of answers would help this site and I found many interesting things here so I hope we will get out of the beta at some day.

Comment: Right, so we/community should do something to encourage people to accept and vote (up and down both) answers, as a part of teaching/instructing new members that how this community works and how this can be pull out of Beta. Percentage of Answers accepted and voted are very low as compared to SO and other Stack Exchange sites (like Travel). Again accepting and voting will encourage more members to participate.

Comment: I don't know if it's far to compare us to Travel, which has already graduated. Of the 20 oldest beta sites, we are in 14th place for accepted answer percentage. So it's a little behind, but not super behind. Our questions per day, although low, is in 8th of those sites. The only way to graduate is to boost QPD, and the best way to do that is through returning askers.

Comment: I have updated the question for the image of the message shown over SO. Please have a look over it :)